# How to map front page with apache proxy ?

Tags: apache, proxy, httpd.conf

I'm proxying calls like

http://myDomain/myApp/anyPath

to the app server

http://myDomain:8080/myApp/anyPath

by the virtual host entry

```
ProxyPass /myApp/ http://myDomain:8080/myApp/
ProxyPassReverse /myApp/ http://myDomain/myApp/
```

However, I want a different mapping for the front page:

http://myDomain/myApp/

should be mapped to

http://myDomain:8080/myApp/frontPage.html

and vice versa in the reverse direction.

Can somebody please explain, how to adjust the virtual host ?